# In SAS, Fisher's exact without Chi-square statistics?

Tags: sas, statistics

In SAS, is it possible to generate Fisher's exact statistics for a 2 x 2 table without getting output from the various Chi-square tests?

[This page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_freq_sect021.htm) indicates calling the Fisher's exact in proq freq will always generate Chi-square results. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Do you want to not display the Chi-Square tests? ODS Exclude is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Reeza Since this answered OP's issue, don't forget to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ODS EXCLUDE` to exclude tables you don't want to see in your output. Conversely, you can use `ODS SELECT` to display only the tables of interest. 
Table Names are ODS table names that you can find from the documentation or via `ODS TRACE`.